# Haproxy issue with Openshift

Tags: openshift, locomotivecms

I am running a multisite instance of [Locomotive CMS](http://locomotivecms.com/) on a scalable Openshift cartridge.

The issue I am having is that haproxy sends GET requests to the root of each Apache instance, returning an erroneous 404, because no host is specified.

Locomotive works fine, but needs a host to each request, so it will serve the appropriate website.

How can I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try sshing into your gear and modifying the ~/haproxy/haproxy.cfg to check a different url instead of / to make sure that your application is up and running.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't make a difference. Locomotive needs a host, not a path.